# Magento - How to show the confimation,success,error in a lightbox popup window

Tags: php, javascript, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I want to show the confimation,success,error messages in a lightbox popup or in an alert window.

For example: Someone subscribes a newsletter, and the success message appears in the layout. Now I don’t want it to be displayed like this. I need the message to be opened in a popup or in an alert window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to show the confimation/success/error messages in a lightbox popup or in an alert window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8148242/693207)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php if($this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()){ ?>
 <script> //apply your script here to pop up    </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not work for me,I want to add my newsletter subcription message in light box.please help if there is orther way to do this